# get mysql export download url in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing an app with PHP(a telegram Bot). one of this app's jobs is to export the data from a table and send it to user. I have used this:

```
$file = '/home/admin/domains/mydomain/public_html/subdomian/mybot/data.ods';
mysqli_query($this->db, "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$file' FROM `{$this->text}`");
```

but the query didn't and when I ran the query in phpmyadmin, I got the access denied error.
at first I thought that I can't export from database(because of limited access) but when I went to export tab in phpmyadmin and push the go button(to export data from database) and my browser started to download the exported `.sql` file. so I think my database user doesn't have access to save files in host.
So how can I find (or create) and exported data link?

Can I do this without SELECTing all data in database and saving them agian into a folder in my host?

all I want is a link to exported data.

Comment: Please show the complete error message

Answer (score 0):

To perform SELECT INTO OUTFILE your MySQL account needs the FILE privilege : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file. You could study phpMyAdmin's source code to see how it exports and offers to save the resulting file via a browser.